# How i can display article filter by age in expressionengine?

Tags: ee2

I have some article in expression engine now i want to display article filter by age range like (1-10 ,10-20 etc..) and cost wise like(low,medium,high) so please guide me how i can do filtration of article...
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs) module for such type filtration. See this the reference from here: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#form-tag-ranges